# How is Windows CE different from Desktop windows?

Tags: windows, windows-ce

How is Windows CE distinct from the other desktop Windows?

Quote from Wiki:

> Windows CE is a distinct operating system and kernel, rather than a
>   trimmed-down version of desktop Windows.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: That WinCE is not just a small Windows, but a OS on it´s own?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question as outlined in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You may be able to find help on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kernel` is the central piece of any `operating system` which is manages every aspect of a operating system.

So each operating systems like `Unix`, `Windows` have their own `kernel` which makes it different form each other. Similarly, `Windows CE` is different from your normal personal computer versions of operating system

Personal computing OS may include `Windows 7`, `Windows 8`, `Windows XP` etc

But `Windows CE` is not another version of the above mentioned Operating Systems, but a different one. This compact edition is specifically designed for a particular task may be like Car Computer, TV, etc..

By `Trimmed down` it tries to convey you that this Kernel cannot help with all tasks that your desktop can do and also its size is possibly less than that of your normal desktop OS